# Issue with LinkedIn API request returning 404 error

Tags: python, flask, linkedin-api

I'm facing an issue with a Flask application that integrates with the LinkedIn API using the Flask-OAuthlib library. The purpose of the application is to authenticate users via LinkedIn and retrieve their profile information. However, I'm encountering a 404 error when trying to make a specific API request to retrieve user data. Below is a detailed description of the setup and the problem:

```
import io
import json
import logging

import openai
import requests
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, session, redirect, abort, url_for
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth
from pip._vendor import cachecontrol

# Flask app setup
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "secret_key"

# OAuth setup with LinkedIn
oauth = OAuth(app)
linkedin = oauth.remote_app(
   'Ety',
   consumer_key='YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY',
   consumer_secret='YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET',
   request_token_params={
       'scope': ['email', "w_member_social", "profile", "openid"]
   },
   base_url='https://api.linkedin.com/v2/',
   request_token_url=None,
   access_token_method='POST',
   access_token_url='https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken',
   authorize_url='https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
)

# LinkedIn tokengetter function
@linkedin.tokengetter
def get_linkedin_oauth_token():
   return session.get('linkedin_token')

# LinkedIn login route
@app.route('/auth/linkedin')
def linkedin_login():
   return linkedin.authorize(callback=url_for('linkedin_authorized', _external=True))

# LinkedIn authorized route
@app.route('/auth/linkedin/authorized')
def linkedin_authorized():
   response = linkedin.authorized_response()
   if response is None or response.get('access_token') is None:
       return 'Access denied: reason={} error={}'.format(
           request.args['error_reason'],
           request.args['error_description']
       )

   session['linkedin_token'] = (response['access_token'], '')

   access_token = response['access_token']
   headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}

   me_response = linkedin.get('/userinfo', headers=headers)  # The problematic request
   me_data = me_response.data
   print(me_response.status)
   print(me_data)

   linkedin_id = me_data['sub']
   session['linkedin_id'] = linkedin_id
   session['name'] = me_data['name']

   return redirect('/')
```

## Issue:

The line me_response = linkedin.get('/userinfo', headers=headers) results in a 404 error. The OAuth process seems to work, but the specific API request to retrieve user data fails.

## Expected Outcome:

I expect the linkedin.get('/userinfo', headers=headers) request to successfully retrieve the user's profile data from LinkedIn's API without a 404 error.

## Additional Information:

Flask-OAuthlib is used for OAuth authentication.
The application's LinkedIn API credentials (consumer key and secret) are properly configured.
The requested scope includes email, w_member_social, profile, and openid.
Note that the requested scopes r_emailaddress and r_liteprofile are not included in the scope list due to specific LinkedIn API restrictions.
Any insights or solutions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just by reading the docs, what I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext)

You need to replace it with the following code.

```
me_response = linkedin.get('/me', headers=headers)
```

Do try it once!

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this request needs  r_basicprofile scopes, which I don't have in the LinkedIn app